# Why keep multiple snapshots in Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

Why would one want to keep multiple snapshots in Nexus instead of just one?

I now have a daily scheduled task in Nexus to remove snapshots.

Settings are:

- Minimum snapshot count: 3
- Snapshot retention (days): 2

Why not keep just one snapshot?

Asking to reduce disk space needed.

Comment: How large is the consumption in your case with SNAPSHOT's ? (Which Nexus version do you use?

Comment: Still stuck on 2.10. Problem is that I have some very large artifacts. Installers of 1Gb. Maybe Nexus isn't even suited for that kind of artifacts...

Comment: On 2.10 ? Oh my... you should at least upgrade to most recent 2.X version... 1 GB. size is not uncommon. I had projects with much larger things... But the question is the needed size currently and furthermore why is that really a problem and why not upgraded to Nexus 3.X...

Comment: Yeah. Good questions... ;-) Time management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases one SNAPSHOT suffices.

Sometimes people reference SNAPSHOT versions via timestamp to fix a specific one. Then it makes sense to keep more than one.